# Automatically export strings for internationalization in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, internationalization

If I am using an npm module such as [i18n](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node), the keys are stored in language specific files such as locale/en.js or locale/de.js:

```
en.js
{
  "hello world": "hello world"
}
```

Is there a tool to export strings using their format, e.g. _("Hello world"), and automatically insert them into the langauge files as is for en.js, and for other language files an empty string, e.g. "new key": "" to take out some of the leg work of having to add them while coding all the time.

As an example: If I add a new string _("some str"), a new key "some str": "some str" will be added to en.js and "some str": "" to de.js upon running the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the object, you can use `fs` to save it to a `js` file or a `json` file.

test.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
try {
  var en = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('en.js'))
  var de = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('de.js'))
} catch(err) {
  // no file present
  en = {};
  de = {};
}
var string = process.env.string;
en[string] = string;
de[string] = "";
console.log(JSON.stringify(en), JSON.stringify(de))
fs.writeFile('en.js', JSON.stringify(en))
fs.writeFile('de.js', JSON.stringify(de))
```

And as you can see, the `string` variable is just a `env` parameter.

```
string=hello node test.js
```

Or you can just save them to a `json` file

```
fs.writeFile('en.json', JSON.stringify(en))
fs.writeFile('de.json', JSON.stringify(de))
```

Be careful if you are using this script along with the script that is consuming the object. As `writeFile` is an `async` operation

Comment: actually that's quite a nice way of doing it, thanks for the response